# A standard name of a strongly extremal point of a convex set

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, convex-geometry, convexity, convex-analysis

I need to name somehow points $x$ of a bounded convex set $C$ in a Banach space $X$ such that the set $$\{x^*\in X^*:x^*(x)=\max x^*[C]\}$$ of support functionals at $x$ has non-empty interior in the dual Banach space $X^*$. I have a feeling that such points already have some standard names (I would suggest *corner* points, *conical* points or something like that) but cannot find a corresponding definition in the literature. Please help!

Comment: I don't know if it's a standard name, but to me it seems natural to call such a point a "vertex".

Comment: @YoavKallus Good suggestion especially in terms of duality between cells of maximal and minimal dimension. Thank you.

Comment: In "On the Geometry of Numerical Ranges" by Radjabalipour and Radjavi, Pacific J. Math, Vol. 61, No. 2, 1975 where they worked in the two dimensional case, they called such points _sharp points_; unfortunately in the applied math literature "sharp points" seems have to be taken to have a different meaning in higher dimensions.

Comment: In "Sets of matrices with given joint numerical range" by N. Krupnik, I.M. Spitkovsky / Linear Algebra and its Applications 419 (2006) 569–585, you have at least a precedent for calling it conical point. The definition they gave is that given a closed set $F$, $x\in F$ is a conical point if and only if there exists a proper, closed, convex cone $K$ such that $F\subset x + K$.

Comment: @WillieWong What is a proper cone? As I understand, a hyperplane is not a proper cone?

Comment: Definition of a proper cone is unfortunately frequently user dependent. But in the context it seems to mean "salient" (= "not containing a full line") + "full dimensional"; I'm not sure without reading through the paper in detail. For your purposes since you are looking at the dual picture, "salient" is the key part that you want.

Comment: @WillieWong You are right. Usually a convex cone is defined as a wedge $C$ such that $C\cap (-C)=\{0\}$. In this case this is exactly what I need (closed convex cones). Thank you.